# Deserialize json to Dictionary<string, string> in C# applicaiton

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

I have this class:

```
public class ParseJson
    {
        private HttpClient _client;

        public ParseJson()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
        }
        public async Task<List<Calibration>> LoadJsonAsync()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Json\\calibration.json"))
            {
                string responseString = r.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("responseString: " + responseString);

                try
                {
                    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseString);
                
                    if ((values["DataType"]).Equals("Calibration_Symptoms"))
                    {

                        calibrationClass.CalibrationData(values: values);

                        }
                    }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Json Exception: " + e);
                }


                List<Calibration> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Calibration>>(responseString);
                return items;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run it I get this exception:

> Json Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "DataType" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'. Path '', line 1, position 10. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String].
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
> at HelloWorld.ParseJson.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\HelloWorld\ParseJson.cs:line 31

I know I can create a model and deserialize to that but ultimately I'd like different Json's to be read in and deserialized.

Is there any way I can deserialize it to `Dictionary<string, string>`?

FYI this is the json I'm currently using:

```json
"DataType": "Calibration_Symptoms",
    "playerHeight": 1.6739861965179443,
    "armSpan": 1.572389006614685,
    "calibratedHeadPosition": {
        "x": 0.10129322111606598,
        "y": 1.6739861965179443,
        "z": -0.01975761353969574
    },
    "symptomSeverity": 0,
    "scat5SymptomsQs": [],
    "rightHanded": true,
    "rightFooted": true,
    "testType": false,
    "trialSymptomsQs": {
        "Gait": [1, 2, 3],
        "Balance1": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Just search on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to `var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseString);`.

Comment: And it all worked?